# OpenGL errors only on AMD hardware

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm developing an OpenGL program. It works well when using Nvidia hardware (tested on gtx 550ti, gtx 780 and gtx 680, on windows and linux). It even works on Intel integrated graphics (a modern Intel atom). However, I'm having a lot of troubles with AMD hardware. I fixed some shader errors but it fails anyway. I have 2 different laptops with AMD graphics (and Windows 7):

- Laptop A: the program starts and most things gets rendered but some aren't. My program uses OpenGL 4.0, I checked that this graphics card supports it, and I have the latest drivers, but if I ask GLFW an OpenGL 4.0 context it fails. My solution was not asking a particular context. I'm getting some shader warnings and some OpenGL errors:

  - "'layout' : symbol is deprecated in current GLSL version "
  - 'gl_' : reserved built-in prefix in GLSL version 1.10 and 1.20
  - invalid enum (per frame)
  - (null) (only on a few frames).
- Laptop B: this time asking an OpenGL 4.0 context doesn't fail, but I get a black screen, nothing is shown. There's only one OpenGL error (per frame): "(null)".

I don't know how can I find the problems. Moreover, I don't have direct access to these laptops (they belong to a friend).

Comment: Judging by some of the errors, you forgot to add `#version ...` to the top of your shader. NV implementations tend to be very permissive about this, and will only give you a ***warning*** when you implicitly use something not in `#version 110` (default), other implementations treat it as an error.

Comment: No... I wrote: "#version 400 core" in all shaders

Comment: Well, `core` is redundant, starting with GLSL 1.50 `core` is the default. You would need to write `#version 400 compatibility` if your shader actually uses any `gl_...` built-in variables. Can you paste one of the shaders that is causing these problems?

Comment: I'm using gl_FragCoord(`ivec2 a=ivec2(clamp(gl_FragCoord.x, 1, 254),
    clamp(gl_FragCoord.y, 1, 254));`) and gl_Position(`gl_Position = VP * wp;`). I thought that gl_Position is not deprecated, is it? How can I replace gl_FragCoord? I know I can just read a vertex shader output, but I prefer reading a pixel value. Note: I also want to remove those warnings, but I think that this is not the problem.